# Cloudant find Query with $and and $or elements

Tags: cloudant

I'm using the following json to find results in a Cloudant

`{
                    "selector": {
                        "$and": [
                            {
                                "type": {
                                    "$eq": "sensor"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "v": {
                                    "$eq": 2355
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$or": [
                                    {
                                        "p": "#401000103"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "p": "#401000114"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "t_max": {
                                    "$gte": 1459554894
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "t_min": {
                                    "$lte": 1459509591
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "fields": [
                        "_id",
                        "p"
                    ],
                    "limit": 200
                }`

If I run this againt my cloudant database I get the following error:

`{
  "error": "unknown_error",
  "reason": "function_clause",
  "ref": 3379914628
}`

If I remove one the $or elements I get the results for query.
(`,{"p":"#401000114"}`)

Also i get a result if I replace #401000114 with #401000114 I get result.
But when I want to use both element I get the error code above.

Can anybody tell what this error_reason: **function_clause** mean?

Answer (score 2):

`error_reason: function_clause` means there was a problem on the server, you should probably reach out to Cloudant Support and see if they can help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had contact with the Cloudant support.
This is there answer:
     The issue affects Cloudant generally
     It affects both mult-tenant and dedicated clusters.

There are working on the sollution.

A workaround is in the array to which the $or operator applies has two elements, you can get the correct result by repeating one of the items in the array.